# Clicking on first instance of class with Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I have a table with a column of buttons in the final column, I am wanting to test that these buttons are working as expect and i am trying to grab the first button on the page ( first button in last cell of first row ) but i am having problems selecting it, I have been looking around for a solution but so far no solutions have worked;

```
->click('.btn.btn-danger.btn-xs:first')
->click('.btn.btn-danger.btn-xs:nth-child(1)')
->click('.btn.btn-danger.btn-xs:first-child')
```